# MSVC linker error with explicit specialisation of inline variable template in namespace initialised via proxy

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

Consider the following C++:

```
struct proxy {
    int operator=(int x) {
        return x;
    }
};

namespace foo {
    template<typename T>
    inline int bar = 0;
}

template<>
inline int foo::bar<int> = proxy{} = 42;

int main() {}
```

(Live example here: https://godbolt.org/z/j8Gqj8r39)

This code causes the following linker error on MSVC only (GCC and Clang are ok):

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int bar<int>" (??$bar@H@@3HA)
```

Which is strange because there's only 1 translation unit, all the symbols are fully defined, and `bar` isn't even accessed.

The error seems to only occur if all of the following are true:

- `bar` is in a namespace
- `bar` is templated
- The specialisation of `bar` is at global scope
- The specialisation of `bar` is `inline`
- The specialisation of `bar` is initialised via `proxy`

Given the bizarre circumstances I can only think that it's undefined behaviour (no idea how that could occur though) or a bug with the MSVC compiler/linker. What's going on here?

<sub>P.S. please don't ask why I need to write strange code like this...</sub>

Comment: The `proxy` construct is not required. The error occurs always if the initializer is not a constant expression, e.g. `int f() { return 0; } /*...*/ template<>
inline int foo::bar<int> = f();` has the same effect.

Comment: If it is moved inside `namespace foo {
template<>
inline int bar<int> = proxy{} = 42;
}`, then there is no error.